# Custom UIButton image buttontype

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uikit

If you can set a button's image even if it's button type is rounded rectangle, then what is the purpose of the button type to begin with? I usually use the custom button type, but does this in fact actually make a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UIButtonType` to make a button of a standard type: a detail disclosure, an info, and so on. In these cases you would not need to set the image at all - the system will do it for you automatically.

When you pick rounded rectangle and set the image, the image would be clipped to the rounded rectangle's border; when you pick custom style, there will be no clipping.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this definitely makes a difference. For example, if you have two buttons, One RoundRect and the other 2nd Custom.

Try to set a background color on both buttons. You will see the difference. The Custom Button has occupied the background color properly and the round rect has few issues.

Even with background Image, you can check both. The Custom button has no issues with setting images, as it has a transparent background and the round rect will have an issue on its corners.

`UIButtonType` definitely have difference of this.

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I am referring to the button's image, not the button's background image.

Comment: I understood this but what if your button has image and text both and you want a transperant or custom background or your button's frame is larger than your image's height width? at that time custom button will be helpful.